# rounding results of summarize function in R

Tags: r

I am using the mtcars data set and trying to obtain a rounded result for the measures of central tendency (min, q1, q2, mean, q3, max) using round however this is producing an error-- is there a way to round off to 2 decimal places?

```
   mtcars_summary <- mtcars %>%
      group_by(cyl) %>%
       summarize(round(min = min(mpg, na.rm=TRUE),2),
          round(q1 = quantile(mpg, 0.25, na.rm=TRUE), 2), 
          round(q2 = quantile(mpg, 0.5, na.rm=TRUE), 2),
          round(mean = mean(mpg, na.rm=TRUE), 2), 
          round(q3 = quantile(mpg, 0.75, na.rm=TRUE),2),
          round(max = max(mpg, na.rm=TRUE)), 2)
```

Comment: The rounding needs to happen before assignment: `min = round(min(mpg, na.rm=TRUE), 2)`

Comment: ...or do all the rounding after, `summarize(min = min(mpg, na.rm = TRUE), q1 = quantile...) %>% mutate(across(everything(), \(x) round(x, 2)))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)
(mtcars_summary <- mtcars %>%
  group_by(cyl) %>%
  summarize(across(mpg,
    .fns = list(
      q1 = \(x)quantile(x, 0.25, na.rm = TRUE),
      q2 = \(x)quantile(x, 0.5, na.rm = TRUE),
      mean = \(x)mean(x, na.rm = TRUE),
      q3 = \(x)quantile(x, 0.75, na.rm = TRUE),
      max = \(x)max(x, na.rm = TRUE)
    ),
    .names = "{.fn}"
  )) |>
  mutate(across(-cyl, \(x)round(x, digits = 2))))
```